# Ubuntu 20.10 high CPU usage

Tags: performance, cpu, 20.10

I upgraded from ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 20.10 and after that, my CPU usage is very high. Moreover, if I open any application then first it takes too much time to open and then it lags too much.

I am on the desktop with no application open and connect an external mouse then not even that works correctly.

please help

the output of `top`

[image]

[image]

`grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_driver`

> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_driver:intel_pstate

`grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_governor`

> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor:powersave
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_governor:powersave
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_governor:powersave
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_governor:powersave

`grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/*`

> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/available_governors:ladder menu teo
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_driver:intel_idle
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_governor:menu
> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_governor_ro:menu

Comment: your browser is running in the background so it might increase CPU usage

Comment: with or without it there no difference in performance..too much lag plus the mouse pointer doesn't move properly with an external mouse

Comment: what processor model? Do `grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo`, some generation of i5? What kernel? Do `uname -a`. top does not show you if the CPU is scaling up frequency. i.e. in case of not responding to high load. Higher load at lower CPU frequency to to the same thing is typically better for power consumption. But yes, it still needs to be responsive. Anyway, suggest (as I always do) that you watch things with turbostat. suggest: `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 6` (something I pretty much always have running.)

Comment: Oh, and perhaps try the performance governor, at least just for a test.

Comment: Is the zombie process persistent? A short term zombie is not too out of the ordinary, but longer shouldn't be.